# Paginação de um grande array em reactJS

Tags: javascript, react, paginação

Estou puxando um array com um tamanho de mais ou menos 20.000.
Porém, na hora da paginação, todas as páginas disponíveis aparecem no meu campo de paginação.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém queria limitar, pra que aparecessem apenas 3 números e tipo,
1 2 3 ... 10

```
  render({
    const indexOfLastUser = currentPage * usersPerPage
    const indexOfFirstUser = indexOfLastUser - usersPerPage
    const currentUsers = users.slice(indexOfFirstUser, indexOfLastUser)

    const pageNumbers = []
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(users.length / usersPerPage); i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i)
    }

    const renderPageNumbers =
      <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          {pageNumbers.map(number => {
            return (
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onClick={this.handleClick} key={number} id={number}>{number}</a></li>
            )
          })}
          <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

     return(
      {renderPageNumbers}
     )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, eu consegui da seguinte forma

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate'

const users = [
    {
        name: 'DD'
    },
    {
        name: 'Ruan'
    },
    {
        name: 'Reginaldo'
    },
    {
        name: 'Renan'
    },
    {
        name: 'DD'
    },
    {
        name: 'Ruan'
    },
    {
        name: 'Reginaldo'
    },
    {
        name: 'Renan'
    },
    {
        name: 'DD'
    },
    {
        name: 'Ruan'
    },
    {
        name: 'Reginaldo'
    },
    {
        name: 'Renan'
    },
    {
        name: 'DD'
    },
    {
        name: 'Ruan'
    },
    {
        name: 'Reginaldo'
    },
    {
        name: 'Renan'
    },
]

export default class Teste2 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            offset: 0,
            users: users,
            elements: [],
            perPage: 2,
            currentPage: 0,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.receivedData()
    }

    setElementsForCurrentpage() {
        let elements = this.state.users
            .slice(this.state.offset, this.state.offset + this.state.perPage)
            .map((users, index) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <p>{users.name}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        this.setState({ elements: elements })
    }

    handlePageClick = (users) => {
        const selectedPage = users.selected;
        const offset = selectedPage * this.state.perPage;
        this.setState({
            currentPage: selectedPage,
            offset: offset
        }, () => {
            this.setElementsForCurrentpage()
        })
    }

    receivedData() {
        this.setState({
            users: this.state.users,
            pageCount: Math.ceil(this.state.users.length / this.state.perPage)
        }, () => this.setElementsForCurrentpage())
    }

    render() {
        let paginationElement
        if (this.state.pageCount > 1) {
            paginationElement = (
                <ReactPaginate
                    previousLabel={"← Previous"}
                    nextLabel={"Next →"}
                    breakLabel={<span className="gap">...</span>}
                    pageCount={this.state.pageCount}
                    onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
                    forcePage={this.state.currentPage}
                    containerClassName={"pagination"}
                    previousLinkClassName={"previous_page"}
                    nextLinkClassName={"next_page"}
                    disabledClassName={"disabled"}
                    activeClassName={"active"}
                />
            );
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Teste</p>
                {paginationElement}
                {this.state.elements}
                {paginationElement}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```